Java Package can't import mypack.*
I have 2 java files in mypack that have package mypack;
i have a third java file that tries to import them
when i use import mypack.*; it doesnt work
when i use import mypack.Package1; import mypack.Package2; it works
I tried including more of the file path, but this wasn't included in the package statement so I did not have much hope that it would solve the issue and it did not. I can still only import each file of the package individually.
cannot access Package2
bad source file: Package2.java
file does not contain class Package2

cannot access Package2 bad source file: Package2.java file does not contain class Package2 Are you really calling classes by names beginning with "Package"? That's very confusing. If you are, then those weird class names have to be exactly the same as the file name

It sounds to me like: 1. You have some old artifacts (.class files) on your system with "mypack" package, and 2. You aren't using the correct path on the compiler to pick up the current "mypack" .class files.  Clean and rebuild everything, delete old .class files manually if necessary, and re-check the path the compiler is using to its build artifacts.

Read [ask] then [edit] the question to add a [mre]. And use [code block] to format code and logs.
